# How can I pass parameters/filters into my DoCmd.OutputTo Method?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm having a very hard time trying to add a parameter into my DoCmd.OutputTo Method. I can export my report successfully, but when I add a parameter or filter, either it gives me an error, or the parameter simply does not work.

I'm using VB.net application, and I tried writing the same arguments I utilize for printing a report. Unfortunately, this arguments do not work on exporting to PDF. this is line I'm having issues.

```
AC.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\Testing\OvertimeRequest.accdb")
AC.DoCmd.OutputTo(Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, "OT Weekly Report", ".pdf", path & "\" & filename,, "OTDate > # " & Today & " # ",, Access.AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint)
AC.CloseCurrentDatabase()
```

I'm expecting to export the report with the all records after Today's date, but instead I get all the records.

Comment: do bevor you output a AC.DoCmd.OpenReport like here explained https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=export-filtered-access-report-pdf-docmd-outputto

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That solved my issue. I needed to first Open the Report then create criteria prior to Export it.

Comment: Well, the outputTo command does not have a filter option, nor a filter parameter. So, you open the form/report and supply a "where" clause, and thus the  report output is now limited. So, you don't open the report, and THEN filter it, you supply a where clause. and don't forget to close the report after.